# Script6.groovy: : Unexpected input: Jmeter JSR233 preprocessor error

Tags: jmeter, preprocessor, jsr223

I am trying to import a jar(imported the jar in testplan) and use the methods to help generate a digital signature in my XML message. But I am seeing the groovy error:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script6.groovy: 7: Unexpected input: '(' @ line 7, column 59.
   alSignatureFactory.getInstance("C\:\Proj
                                 ^
```

The code is simple and is as below. why is this complaining at the '('

```
import com.aciworldwide.generic.stress.simulator.crypto.xml.signing.DigitalSignature;
import com.aciworldwide.generic.stress.simulator.crypto.xml.signing.DigitalSignatureFactory;
import java.util.*
import groovy.xml.*


DigitalSignature sig = DigitalSignatureFactory.getInstance("C:\Projects\NFRPERF\trunk\BI-Fast_CI_HUB\jmeterscripts\crypto\server.keys.p12", "server.key.pair", "aciworldwide", "PKCS12");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to either escape these backward slashes with another backward slash, i..e

```
"C:\\Projects\\NFRPERF\\trunk\\BI-Fast_CI_HUB\\jmeterscripts\\crypto\\server.keys.p12"
```

or use forward slashes instead:

```
"C:/Projects/NFRPERF/trunk/BI-Fast_CI_HUB/jmeterscripts/crypto/server.keys.p12"
```

or use Groovy's [Slashy String](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_slashy_string):

```
/C:\Projects\NFRPERF\trunk\BI-Fast_CI_HUB\jmeterscripts\crypto\server.keys.p12/
```

More information:

- [Escaping Characters in Java](https://codegym.cc/groups/posts/escaping-characters-java)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you Dimitri. That was really helpful!!. The second solution worked